# What image resources are available in .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

In Visual Studio, when I add a toolbar (a.k.a toolstrip) to my WinForms form, I have an option of adding "Standard Items". This populates it with thing like "New", "Open", "Cut", "Copy", etc. All these buttons have nice icons, but they are not added to my project. When I check the code, they are populated like this:

```
this.newToolStripButton.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("newToolStripButton.Image")));
this.openToolStripButton.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("openToolStripButton.Image")));
this.saveToolStripButton.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("saveToolStripButton.Image")));
.
.
.
```

Where are these images coming from? Are there others I can use? Are they documented anywhere?

**BONUS:** Is the list of which items get added when selecting to "Insert Standard Items" documented anywhere, or do I just need to try and see what I get?

Comment: [ResourceManager.GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject) from a Bitmap stored in its [PropertyStore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyStore.cs,19), stored when a specific object is created. The Bitmap if retrieved from the assembly container using the [Bitmap(Type, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Type_System_String_) Bitmap constructor.

Comment: E.g., [BindingNavigator.MoveFirstImage](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingNavigator.cs,192)

Comment: I downloaded image collection for VS19. These libraries are available from microsoft

Comment: [The Visual Studio image library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/the-visual-studio-image-library?view=vs-2019)